# Glassfish returning attributes to C# client, but not to Java Client

Tags: c#, web-services, glassfish

I have a web service developed with Axis2 and deployed on Glassfish 4.0.  When my java built client access the service, my xml comes back clean with no attributes, but when I attempt to pull data from a C# client, two of the elements have xsi defined attributes embedded in them and the C# client fails to parse the message.

There must be something wrong with how I implemented the client on the C# side or possibly the way I implemented the service on the server side.

**snippet from the successful response message**
`<coordinates>`
`<latitude>38.582886969023164</latitude>`
`<longitude-77.52012364626299</longitude>`
`</coordinates>`


**matching snippet from the unsuccessful response message**
`<coordinates>`
`<latitude xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="latitude_type0">38.582886969023164</latitude>`
`<longitude xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="longitude_type0">- 77.52012364626299</longitude>`
`</coordinates>`

Comment: Further reading has led me to this (from http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-whichwsdl/):  

A note about xsi:type and literal use
Although in normal circumstances xsi:type does not appear in a literal WSDL's SOAP message, there are still cases when type information is necessary and it will appear -- in polymorphism, for instance. If the API expects a base type and an extension instance is sent, the type of that instance must be provided for proper deserialization of the object.

Comment: It turns out I am using an extension type here. My latitude element is a complexType with simpleContent extending from latitudeType and containing an accuracy attribute. It's an inheritance relationship.